# Shutting down from Putty

Tags: linux

If I am using command from putty logged-in i.e. ssh -t root@192.168.1.11 "sudo poweroff" then what will happen to server ? Will it be directly poweroff without shutting down oracle database if database is running in server. And if yes then what will happen when we restart the server ?

please guide. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a:

```
sudo poweroff
```

should stop all services and then shutdown if I understand the poweroff sequence right. It should be the same as shutting down from within your desktop environment. So the Oracle database will be shut down, and the terminal will exit.

To start and stop the database have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32009/strt_stp.htm). And to just exit the terminal simply type:

```
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `sudo poweroff` will going to shutdown the server.

And Yes, it will going to shutdown also the oracle  database server installed into it.

When you restart the server. Here is what happen.

1. It will going to stop the all running services (ex. oracle server )
2. It will poweroff the machine.
3. then it will booted again and start all service ( all services included on startup of server)